# How to open a xls file with Excel in VB

Tags: vb.net, excel

So, how can I tell the system to open the file for me? I've tried

```
Shell(ExcelFilePath)
```

But an exception was thrown although the file path is from OpenFileDialog.FileOk

So, I am trying to play with Excel.Application, is it possible to open the file with that?

Comment: do you want to open excel app outside of your app or excel sheet in your application.?

Comment: Outside of my application

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will open the file with Excel:

```
Process.Start("EXCEL.EXE", """C:\Folder\file.xls""")
```

Being the second string the arguments for the process. See the [MSDN Dcoumentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: It worked, thanks! I will mark you as the correct answer later.

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("FilePath")
```

it will open the file in an application associated with it.